# Help identifying these audio/video connectors coming from a backup camera

Tags: connectors

[image]

I need help identifying the two connectors.

1. The one marked "AV-IN". My guess is 2.5mm TRRRS?
2. The yellow connector. I think it might start with "R", but I completely forgot.

Any help in identifying please!
Or help in figuring out which stack i should post this in

Comment: please add clear closeup pictures of the connectors ... also include dimensions of the connectors

Comment: TRRRS means `Tip Ring Ring Ring Sleeve` ... is that what you have?

Comment: The picture shows 4-pole, TRRS -probably 3.5 mm.